# Leer enteros dentro de archivos que pertenecen a un directorio y mostrarlos en pantalla

Tags: c

soy nuevo aqui,y estoy aprendiendo C,y necesito resolver el siguiente problema con C,ya intente de varias formas y no estoy seguro  que me piden,hasta ahora use fopen ,fscanf y alguna otra funcion,pero claro  me funciona mi codigo si hago el mismo aparte, sin usar esas funciones que me dan,entonces quiero entender bien donde usar estos parametros de la funcion array_from_file :(int array[],
unsigned int max_size,const char *filepath),lo que supongo que en la funcion array_from_file es para el primer ejercicio y la funcion array_dump es para el segundo por los argumentos que tienen.

EXISTE UN DIRECTORIO LLAMADO input y dentro de el muchos archivos,con nombres diferentes ,y en cada archivo el array se representa con su size y luego cada uno de los
miembros.

por ejemplo el array = [1,2,3,4,5] es representado en el archivo como:

5
1 2 3 4 5

EJERCICIO 1:
Se pide que tu programa principal, lea el array dentro de cada uno de los archivos
dentro de input y que luego de leerlo imprima por pantalla su contenido de la siguiente forma:

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

El codigo lo debo ingresar donde dice TU CODIGO AQUI:

este es el main.c,donde debo agregar codigo :

```html
/* First, the standard lib includes, alphabetically ordered */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Maximum allowed length of the array */
#define MAX_SIZE 100000

void print_help(char *program_name) {
    /* Print the usage help of this program. */
    printf("Usage: %s <input file path>\n\n"
           "Sort an array given in a file in disk.\n"
           "\n"
           "The input file must have the following format:\n"
           " * The first line must contain only a positive integer,"
           " which is the length of the array.\n"
           " * The second line must contain the members of the array"
           " separated by one or more spaces. Each member must be an integer."
           "\n\n"
           "In other words, the file format is:\n"
           "<amount of array elements>\n"
           "<array elem 1> <array elem 2> ... <array elem N>\n\n",
           program_name);
}

char *parse_filepath(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Parse the filepath given by command line argument. */
    char *result = NULL;

    if (argc < 2) {
        print_help(argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = argv[1];

    return (result);
}

unsigned int array_from_file(int array[],
           unsigned int max_size,
           const char *filepath) {
    //TU CODIGO AQUI!!!


}

void array_dump(int a[], unsigned int length) {
    //TU CODIGO AQUI!!!

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *filepath = NULL;

    /* parse the filepath given in command line arguments */
    filepath = parse_filepath(argc, argv);
    
    /* create an array of MAX_SIZE elements */
    int array[MAX_SIZE];
    
    /* parse the file to fill the array and obtain the actual length */
    unsigned int length = array_from_file(array, MAX_SIZE, filepath);
    
    /*dumping the array*/
    array_dump(array, length);
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

para compilar usa:
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o reader main.c

para correr el programa:
./reader input/archivo

donde archivo es alguno de los archivos que se encuentra dentro de input.

### Cambiar el archivo input y ejecutar nuevamente

EJERCICIO 2:
Modificar main.c para que en lugar de leer el archivo input, lea cada uno de los miembros del
array por pantalla y luego los muestre en la misma.

Answer (score 1):

veo que no te han explicado aun muchas cosas. Primero que nada no esta muy bien explicada que seria exactamente tu pregunta, aqui no podemos resolver tu tarea.

Ademas te sugiero que revises los tipos de datos de C ahi te sera mas facil saber que pasar a una funcion por ejemplo.

Si no entiendes los argumentos de las funciones pregunta eso concretamente, creo que te interesa saber que son los argumentos de las funciones:

`array_from_file (int array[], unsigned int max_size,const char *filepath)` lo que le pasas en el **primer argumento** es un array de enteros (que es creado exactamente arriba de donde se llama la funcion), el **segundo argumento** es simplemente unsigned int que es un tipo de dato y esta definido como una constante en las primeras lineas de ese codigo `#define MAX_SIZE 100000`, el **tercer argumento** seria una forma de representar (generalmente) una cadena de caracteres en C que tambien te dan en ese codigo cuando llaman esta funcion `filepath = parse_filepath(argc, argv);`.

Lo que debes hacer aqui es utilizar las funciones que citaste al comienzo como fopen, etc para copiar el contenido de estos archivos dentro del directorio INPUT, puedes ir abriendo los archivos e ir imprimiendolos, o crear un array de 2 dimensiones y almacenarlos alli si te pide que lo hagas, no se entiende muy bien el contexto de tu pregunta debido a que parece incompleta, el ejercicio 2 aun no logro entender como te piden.

Si tienes alguna duda escribeme

Comment: Respondi una pregunta, lo unico que le dije que especifique mejor su forma de preguntar

Comment: hola,gracias por responder,no quiero que hagan mi ejercicio quiero aprender a hacerlo,mi pregunta es, donde hay que usar los 3 argumentos de la funcion array_from_file?, se que tengo que usar fopen,fscanf o fgetc y fclose,entonces en donde irian esos 3 argumentos en esas funciones? y que significa lo declarado en el main :unsigned int length = array_from_file(array, MAX_SIZE, filepath);?

Comment: https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Manejo_de_archivos

Answer (score 0):

Por cómo está planteado el ejercicio MAX_SIZE es el tamaño que tiene siempre el array que creás. Parece como si tus profes de algoritmos y estructuras de datos II (supongo que ese es el nombre de la materia por los contenidos que ves) todavía no les hayan enseñado a crear objetos con memoria dinámica. Lo que parece qje deberías hacer es revisar que la longitud leída en el archivo .in no sobrepase MAX_SIZE, esto lo podés hacer por ejemplo con un assert.

filepath es el archivo que le vas a pasar como primer argumento a la función fopen.

array es el arreglo que vas a modificar, es decir, los valores que vayas leyendo del .in los vas a ir guardando en el arreglo array.

PD:
Aguante famaf e isaac asimov